How to use pdf.js locally
I have a locally running web app in which I would like to extract data from a pdf.  pdf.js would work well for this, but it uses modules, which causes cross origin request errors for the file: protocol.  Running a local web server gets around the CORS issue, but is too complicated of a task for my users.  Is there a way to adjust the code for pdf.js to have it run locally?
locally-installed PDF.JS does not render asked the same question over five years ago, but the answer is two major versions out of date: loading a module as a regular js file doesn't work because of the slightly differing syntax (export becomes a keyword).
Building PDF.js says that npx gulp generic-legacy will generate build/generic/build/pdf[.worker].js (possibly also npx gulp generic; "this" isn't clear).  This statement appears to be incorrect, as running those commands creates the .mjs files, not .js files.
I think this answer means that what I want can be accomplished using Webpack or Rollup, but the answer doesn't specify how, and I haven't been able to figure that out.
(I will be having my users <input> the file using the html widget, so the fact that the pdf is local isn't a problem.)
A sample of working code is:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>pdf.js test</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/4.9.155/pdf.min.mjs" type="module"></script>
<!-- works with all schemes, but pdf.js is remote -->
<!--<script src="pdf.js" type="module"></script>-->
<!-- local pdf.js doesn't work with file:// scheme -->
<!--<script src="pdf.js"></script>-->
<!-- Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="fileUploader" type="file">
        <p>Number of pages: <span id="pageCount"></span></p>
    </body>
    <script>
        //const pdfjsLib = require('pdf.js');
        document.getElementById('fileUploader').addEventListener('change', ({target}) => {
            //pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.js';
            pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
                `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjsLib.version}/pdf.worker.min.mjs`;
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.addEventListener('load', async () => {
                const buffer = reader.result;
                const pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: new Uint8Array(buffer) }).promise;
                const numPages = pdf.numPages;
                document.getElementById('pageCount').textContent = numPages;
            });
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(target.files[0]);
        });
    </script>
</html>


unclear what you want to achieve since if I run your file as a local html it works so I see # runtime_internal_sys · Issue #47773 · golang_go.pdf Number of pages: 3 which is correct for that file. if I pick one with more than a thousand imbeded it correctly reports sample-pdf-portfolio.pdf Number of pages: 1 and one I know should report 341 says Lazarillo de Tormes - Anonimo_cropped.pdf Number of pages: 341 thus the page works as a local file. but agreed it says Refused to cross-origin redirects of the top-level worker script.

@KJ I'd like to have this work as a local html file using a local copy of pdf.js (so, the second script tag).  Ideally, my web app should be able to run in the browser without an internet connection, so it wouldn't be able to use a CDN for the library.
